# What's the relation between 2 points from 2 different planes?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

I'm trying to find the relation between my "text" objects, and my "world" objects. This may be related to development, but I thought this question was better fit for this exchange. I have two different planes, and I would like to find the relation between the coordinates of both of them. Here is what I have :

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by relation. The **text origin** is at $(0,0)$ and the **world origin** is at $(9,5)$. Are you looking for a way, to translate the one plane onto the other? E.g. the translation $(-9,-5)$ applied to the **world plane** would shift it to the **text plane**.

Comment: You can treat the $x$ and $y$ coordinates separately, and then find a linear relation between $x_{text}$ and $x_{world}$ and likewise for $y$.

Comment: @quapka the world origin is also (0,0), just not the same (0,0) as the text origin.

Comment: @Bob1123 Hmm, two different functions, I'll give it a shot thanks.